# WFFM Image upload issue in CD Server Sitecore , Getting error "Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']"

Tags: wffm

In Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519) + Web Forms for Marketers 8.1.rev. 160523,

We are getting problem into executeing WFFM Custom Save Action in CD environment with Submitting form with image. If we do not upload any image and submit the forms, WFFM Custom Save Action work fine. In CM sever form is submitting perfectly with/without image.

In Log file I got this entry against my Save Action Item ID

> WARN [WFFM] Could not find configuration node:
>   databases/database[@id='master']

but already we have setting enable for web db in SwitchMasterToWeb.config & sitecore. analytics.config